# Returning an Array Using Recursion in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I currently have this code:

```
import numpy as np

def mapfeature_binominal_array(x1,x2,n=6,list=[]):

    if len(list)==0:
        list.append(x1)
        list.append(x2)

    if n==1:
        print(np.array(list))
        return np.array(list)
    else:
        for i in range(0,n+1):
            formula=((x1)**(n-i))*((x2)**(i))
            list.append(formula)


        mapfeature_binominal_array(x1,x2,n-1,list)

test_array=mapfeature_binominal_array(-0.25,1.5)
```

which prints out the following output:

```
[ -2.50000000e-01   1.50000000e+00   2.44140625e-04  -1.46484375e-03
   8.78906250e-03  -5.27343750e-02   3.16406250e-01  -1.89843750e+00
   1.13906250e+01  -9.76562500e-04   5.85937500e-03  -3.51562500e-02
   2.10937500e-01  -1.26562500e+00   7.59375000e+00   3.90625000e-03
  -2.34375000e-02   1.40625000e-01  -8.43750000e-01   5.06250000e+00
  -1.56250000e-02   9.37500000e-02  -5.62500000e-01   3.37500000e+00
   6.25000000e-02  -3.75000000e-01   2.25000000e+00]
```

However, when i try:

```
print(test_array)
```

I get `None`.

I am wondering why it does not assign the array to `test_array`.

Comment: You recursively call 6->5->4->3->2->1, but return value only when returning 1->2, but not 2->3-> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never return the result of the *recursive* call:

```
else:
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        formula=((x1)**(n-i))*((x2)**(i))
        list.append(formula)

    mapfeature_binominal_array(x1,x2,n-1,list)
```

The function just ends there without a `return` so `None` is returned instead.

Add `return` there:

```
else:
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        formula=((x1)**(n-i))*((x2)**(i))
        list.append(formula)

    return mapfeature_binominal_array(x1,x2,n-1,list)
```

A recursive function call is just like any other function call; you still need to do something with the result of that function call; the value it returns does not automatically propagate to be the return value of the outer call.

You are also falling into the [default mutable argument value trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument); you set `list=[]` in the function signature and append to that. The values in that list *persist across calls*, so future calls to the function will still have those values from previous calls, and you'll get wrong results.

Use a sentinel like `None` instead, and try to avoid using the names of built-in types like `list`:

```
def mapfeature_binominal_array(x1, x2, n=6, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = [x1, x2]
```

You can immediately set that initial list to `[x1, x2]`.

The corrected code then runs and produces your results:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def mapfeature_binominal_array(x1, x2, n=6, lst=None):
...     if lst is None:
...         lst = [x1, x2]
...     if n == 1:
...         return np.array(lst)
...     else:
...         for i in range(n + 1):
...             formula = (x1 ** (n - i)) * (x2 ** i)
...             lst.append(formula)
...         return mapfeature_binominal_array(x1, x2, n - 1, lst)
...
>>> mapfeature_binominal_array(-0.25, 1.5)
array([ -2.50000000e-01,   1.50000000e+00,   2.44140625e-04,
        -1.46484375e-03,   8.78906250e-03,  -5.27343750e-02,
         3.16406250e-01,  -1.89843750e+00,   1.13906250e+01,
        -9.76562500e-04,   5.85937500e-03,  -3.51562500e-02,
         2.10937500e-01,  -1.26562500e+00,   7.59375000e+00,
         3.90625000e-03,  -2.34375000e-02,   1.40625000e-01,
        -8.43750000e-01,   5.06250000e+00,  -1.56250000e-02,
         9.37500000e-02,  -5.62500000e-01,   3.37500000e+00,
         6.25000000e-02,  -3.75000000e-01,   2.25000000e+00])
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the result of `mapfeature_binominal_array(x1,x2,n-1,list)`.

Comment: but it does have a return statement...when n==1, i,e the breaking condition for the recursion.

Comment: It does return when n==1. But when you called it through `test_array=mapfeature_binominal_array(-0.25,1.5)`, n == 6.

Comment: @gskang: you don't return the *recursive call*.